# Highlight the whole row, not just the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have VBA code pull a color from a cell that has color set by conditional formatting and apply it to the whole row. I have the code below, however, it only applies the color to a specific column. How do I change the code to highlight the whole row and not just the column?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim xSRg, xDRg, xPRG, xISRg, xIDRg As Range
Dim xFNum As Long
On Error Resume Next
Set xSRg = Range("A2:A84")
Set xDRg = Range("B2:B84")
For xFNum = 1 To xSRg.Count
Set xISRg = xSRg.Item(xFNum)
Set xIDRg = xDRg.Item(xFNum)
xIDRg.Interior.Color = xISRg.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
Next xFNum
End Sub
```

Currently it works as seen below, however I would like the color to apply from A13 to J13.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRm8w.jpg)

Comment: Why don't you extend the conditional formatting to the whole row?

Comment: Because, I used another VBA code to set the color of column A, from a different worksheet, if that makes sense.

Comment: `xIDRg.EntireRow.Interior.Color = xISRg.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color`? Note that all the variables declared on the same line as `xIDRg` are implicit `Variant` without a declared type; the correct syntax for a multiple declarations statement is `Dim a As X, b As Y, c As Z`

Comment: I believe the xDRg has to be defined differently but I don't know how to define it.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon thank you, this gets the job done, however, is there a way to cap the row length until Column J?

Comment: `Dim xDRg As Range` ...consider using actual meaningful identifier names that can be naturally pronounced instead of smashing the keyboard to find a variable name! As for limiting to column J, get the Range of columns that starts at column A and ends in column J, then format its range in row `xIDRg.Row`. `Me.Range("A" & xIDRg Row & ":J" & xIDRg.Row)` should do.

Comment: Sorry, I am not exactly sure what I have to do. I don't have much experience with VBA. Would this be the right approach? @MathieuGuindon 
`Set xDRg = xIDRg.Row.Me.Range("A" & xIDRg.Row & ":J" & xIDRg.Row)`
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If it involves doing something with the entire row of any cell a user clicks, you can simply use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Rows(Target.Row).Select
End Sub
```

For example, to apply a background color to the whole row:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Rows(Target.Row).Interior.Color = vbYellow
End Sub
```

In those examples, if the user selects multiple cells, the "top" row of the selected range will be used.

To apply an action to all selected rows, you can loop through them:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim rw
  For Each rw In Target.Rows
    Rows(rw.Row).Interior.Color = vbRed
  Next rw
End Sub
```

...or, to select all the rows from any range of selected cells would be a similar loop, using [Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.application.union) to add each row to a range

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim rw, sel As Range
  For Each rw In Target.Rows  'loop through selected rows
    If sel Is Nothing Then
      Set sel = Rows(rw.Row) 'if this the 1st selected row, store it
    Else
      Set sel = Application.Union(sel, Rows(rw.Row)) 'merge with prev
    End If
  Next rw
  sel.Select 'select range of rows
End Sub
```

Comment: I used this code to match cell color from Conditionally Formatted cell from one sheet to another sheet. 


Now, I would like to extended the cell with matched color to the whole row. I 

And I would like to use the code provided, I just dont know how to define the xDRg to allow me to copy color to entire row from A to J